# How to play Streaming videos on VLC player?

Tags: video, streaming, vlc-media-player

I have got some http://*.sdp, http://*.3gp and http://*.mp4 files which can connect to internet and streams videos. Now I want to stream the videos using VLC player.

How to do this ?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  Does Media->Open Network Stream not work for you?  If not, what doesn't work about it?

Comment: @Heavyd - Yes you are 100% correct. This works very well. Then I want to save this link as some file and retrieve the stream from file.

Comment: If you mean you want to save the stream as a stand alone file which can be played without needing it to be streamed, just do a Google search for "save streaming media" etc.